# Calculate daily maximum, minimum and mean data from weather data recorded at 15 minutes interval

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation, data-mining

Our weather station recorded temperature data at 15 minutes interval. I'd like to calculate daily minimum, daily maximum and daily mean temperatures. How can I do this in R? I believe 15 minutes weather data can be easily converted to daily data but I can't seem to find the code. Here is the glimpse of data

[image]

Here is the reproducible example

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(
  c(
    1401104700,
    1401105600,
    1401106500,
    1401107400,
    1401108300,
    1401109200,
    1401110100,
    1401111000,
    1401111900,
    1401112800,
    1401113700,
    1401114600,
    1401115500,
    1401116400,
    1401117300,
    1401118200,
    1401119100,
    1401120000,
    1401120900,
    1401121800,
    1401122700,
    1401123600,
    1401124500,
    1401125400,
    1401126300,
    1401127200,
    1401128100,
    1401129000,
    1401129900,
    1401130800,
    1401131700,
    1401132600,
    1401133500,
    1401134400,
    1401135300,
    1401136200,
    1401137100,
    1401138000,
    1401138900,
    1401139800,
    1401140700,
    1401141600,
    1401142500,
    1401143400,
    1401144300,
    1401145200,
    1401146100,
    1401147000,
    1401147900,
    1401148800,
    1401149700,
    1401150600,
    1401151500,
    1401152400,
    1401153300,
    1401154200,
    1401155100,
    1401156000,
    1401156900,
    1401157800,
    1401158700,
    1401159600,
    1401160500,
    1401161400,
    1401162300,
    1401163200,
    1401164100,
    1401165000,
    1401165900,
    1401166800,
    1401167700,
    1401168600,
    1401169500,
    1401170400,
    1401171300,
    1401172200,
    1401173100,
    1401174000,
    1401174900,
    1401175800,
    1401176700,
    1401177600,
    1401178500,
    1401179400,
    1401180300,
    1401181200,
    1401182100,
    1401183000,
    1401183900,
    1401184800,
    1401185700,
    1401186600,
    1401187500,
    1401188400,
    1401189300,
    1401190200,
    1401191100,
    1401192000,
    1401192900,
    1401193800
  ),
  tzone = "UTC",
  class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")
),
temperature = c(
  25,
  25.2,
  25.3,
  25.1,
  25.4,
  26,
  25.9,
  25.6,
  26.8,
  27.8,
  26.8,
  26,
  26,
  26.3,
  27,
  27,
  26.2,
  25.8,
  24.9,
  25.1,
  26.3,
  25.6,
  25.3,
  25.2,
  25.1,
  24.8,
  24.7,
  24,
  23,
  22.7,
  22.5,
  22.5,
  22.2,
  21.9,
  21.5,
  21.1,
  20.8,
  20.5,
  20.3,
  20.3,
  20.2,
  20,
  19.8,
  19.6,
  19.2,
  19.1,
  19.1,
  18.9,
  18.8,
  18.6,
  18.3,
  18.2,
  18.2,
  18.2,
  18.1,
  17.9,
  17.8,
  17.7,
  17.8,
  18,
  18.1,
  18,
  18.1,
  18.6,
  18.7,
  18.5,
  18.3,
  18.1,
  18.1,
  18.6,
  18.8,
  18.6,
  18.6,
  18.3,
  18.2,
  18,
  17.8,
  18,
  18.2,
  18.9,
  19.8,
  19.6,
  19.5,
  19.7,
  20.2,
  21.5,
  22.4,
  23,
  24,
  23.3,
  23.2,
  23.7,
  24.5,
  24.8,
  24.9,
  26.3,
  25.7,
  24.9,
  24.9,
  26
)), row.names = c(NA,-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df$date = as.Date(df$date)
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the image showed, the dates are in `month/day/year hour:minutes` format, which could be converted to days by converting to `Date` class, do the grouping by the `Date` and then get the `min/max/mean` of temperature

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
    group_by(date = as.Date(mdy_hm(date))) %>%
    summarise(min_temp = min(temperature, na.rm = TRUE),
              max_temp = max(temperature, na.rm = TRUE),
      mean_temp = mean(temperature, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(min_temp = min(temperature, na.rm = TRUE),
              max_temp = max(temperature, na.rm = TRUE),
              mean_temp = mean(temperature, na.rm = TRUE)),
            by = .(date = as.IDate(date, "%m/%d/%Y"))]
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. Your `data. table` syntax works, but I'd like to use `dplyr`. When I try your `dplyr` code, the `date` column don't parse and I get `NA` in date column. Using only `group_by(date = as.Date(date))`  parses the column, but I get only one row for the entire data

Comment: @Ahsk Probably due to the format in your original data.  I assumed it as month, day, year, hour, minute from the image and not from your dput (as it is just date in year month day)

Comment: It is month, day, year, hour, minute

Comment: @Ahsk in that case `mdy_hm` should work fine.  Maybe there is some missing information;  Can you show a single value of date here

Comment: Here you go `6/24/2017 11:15 AM`

Comment: @Ahsk It is working fine for me `as.Date(mdy_hm("6/24/2017 11:15 AM"))#
[1] "2017-06-24"`

Comment: I just tried again. I am getting a warning and a single row for the entire data. Here is the warning `Warning message:                                                                              
Problem while computing `date = as.Date(mdy_hm(date))`.
ℹ All formats failed to parse. No formats found. `

Comment: @Ahsk Ok, then try just `group_by(date = as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%Y"))`   Probably some dates have incorrect values

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. I got a warning message, but results are fine `"Warning message:                                                                              
Problem while computing `date = as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%Y")`.
ℹ unknown timezone '%m/%d/%Y' `

Comment: @Ahsk maybe there are some time in daylight savings

Answer (score 1):

one option is using `ddply()` from `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
dfsummary <- ddply(df, .(date), summarize
                   ,tmean = mean(temperature, na.rm = T)
                   ,tmin = min(temperature, na.rm = T)
                   ,tmax = max(temperature, na.rm = T)
                   )

dfsummary

        date    tmean tmin tmax
1 2014-05-26 23.55510 18.8 27.8
2 2014-05-27 20.14118 17.7 26.3
```

Comment: Thanks. The above code is giving the same values for each for min,max, mean, but this is due to problem in date parsing in my data. Data.table syntax solves, so thanks for the assistance.